# Visual Basic 2010 Clearing a Picture Box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to build a simple poker game in visual basic studio 2010. When I click btnShuffle I assign the five image place holders the default backside of the card

```
btnShuffle_onClick......

    picFlop1.Image = My.Resources.BlankCard    //saved in my resources folder
    picFlop2.Image = My.Resources.BlankCard    //and so on and so on...

end sub
```

and then in my btnDeal cards I have tried every version of picFlop1.Dispose(), picFlop1.Image = Nothing... etc that I can find and nothing seems to erase the blank image.. I've tried skipping the clear step and just writing the actual face card overtop of the blank card, but it doesn't seem to show threw the initial blank card.. any help would be great..

```
btnDeal_onClick...

   //find first five cards on deck and assign them by overwrite/delete blank card

   picflop1.Image = My.Resource.SomeCard  //Does Not Work
   picFlop1.Image.Dispose()     //Does Not Work
   picFlop1.Image = Nothing     //Does Not Work

end sub
```

***UPDATE***

I am assigning these blank cards... not in the shuffle function but in the timer1 interval function.. could that have anything to do with it? The methods listed above work in a btnReset_onClick

_Matt

Comment: Setting `Image = Nothing` should work. Setting to another image without prior clearing should work too. I just tested both options.

Comment: @Neolisk I agree.. every site says the same thing.. but Neither Option is working for me.. I wonder why...

Comment: Would have them set inside a Timer function have anything to do with it?

Comment: What are you doing in the timer tick event?  Also, make sure you don't have the BackgroundImage set, just the Image property.  Setting the `Image = Nothing` should be all you need.  Any paint events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good call on looking closer at the timer @LarsTech..

Apparently if you don't stop the timer, it will continuously kick out the code to display the backs of the cards.. all the other code was functioning fine, just couldn't see it bc of the timer... Thanks guys.. as always.. your the best!

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
PictureBox1.Image = New Image
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that picFlip is a PictureBox, have you tried Invalidate() and then Update() after setting the new image?

Answer (score 0):

You have to

```
     PictureBox.Image = null
```

After that you can set a new image